# How to determine if OpenSSL and mod_ssl are installed on Apache2

Tags: ssl, apache2

Does anyone know the command to determine if OpenSSL and mod_ssl are installed on Apache2?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm in the process of trying to install a ssl cert. The first step says that i need to ensure that I have OpenSSL and mod_ssl installed. I had assumed I had, as i enabled ssl module and had installed ssl. However when I ran the first command: openssl genrsa –des3 1024 –out www.mydomain.com.key
I got what looked like help information..
So I decided to try and work out if OpenSSl and mod_ssl were installed first before i looked at the command. Hope that explains what im trying to do!
Thanks, Fiona

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you have PHP installed on your server, you can create a php file, let's called it phpinfo.php and add this `<?php echo phpinfo();?>`, and open the file in your browser,  this shows information about your system environment, to quickly find info about your Apache loaded modules, locate 'Loaded Modules' on the resulting page.

Comment: Actually you don't need to 'echo', the function provides it's own output.

Answer (score 32):

If you have PHP installed on your server, you can chek it in runtime using "[extension_loaded](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php)" funciontion. Just like this:

```
<?php
if (!extension_loaded('openssl')) {
    // no openssl extension loaded.
}
?>
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution for example where I'm building a system requirements page for my installer.

Comment: This solution is the best for use in PHP code when we want to make our domain automatically redirect from http: // to https: //, thank you for saving my salary!

Answer (score 24):

Usually, when you compile your apache2 server (or install it by packages facility stuff), you can check any directive that're available to be used by tapping this command:

```
~# $(which httpd) -L | grep SSL # on RHEL/CentOS/Fedora
~# $(which apache2) -L | grep SSL # on Ubuntu/Debian
~# $(which httpd2) -L | grep SSL # on SUSE
```

If you don't see any SSL* directive, it means that you don't have apache2 with mod_ssl compiled.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. Nobody was talking about PHP in the question.

Answer (score 21):

Use the following commands.

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013 (or similar output)
```

**For RHEL/CentOS/Fedora:**

```
$ httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep ssl
ssl_module (shared)
```

**For Ubuntu/Debian**

```
$ apache2 -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep ssl
ssl_module (shared)
```

**For SUSE**

```
$ httpd2 -t -D DUMP_MODULES 2>&1 | grep ssl
ssl_module (shared)
```

Answer (score 20):

The default Apache install is configured to send this information on the **Server** header line.  You can view this for any server using the curl command.

```
$ curl --head http://localhost/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 04 Sep 2009 08:14:03 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.8 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8a DAV/2 PHP/5.2.6 SVN/1.5.4 proxy_html/3.0.0
```

Comment: This is not not helpful when ServerSignature and ServerTokens are set to show limited data in Apache.

Comment: in my case, no openssl appears, though mine is running.  what version OS are we talking about?

Answer (score 10):

Using Apache 2, you can see what modules are currently loaded by the HTTP daemon by running the following command:

```
apache2ctl -M
```

The `-M` option is really just a parameter passed to *httpd*.

> apache2ctl is a front end to the Apache HyperText Transfer Protocol
>   (HTTP) server.  It  is
>          designed to help the administrator control the functioning of the Apache apache2 daemon.
>
> ```
>    NOTE: The default Debian configuration requires the environment variables APACHE_RUN_USER,
>    APACHE_RUN_GROUP, and APACHE_PID_FILE to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars.
>
>    The apache2ctl script returns a 0 exit value on success, and >0 if an error  occurs.   For
>    more details, view the comments in the script.
> ```

Comment: Needed to run this command with `sudo` because when I did like that, it returns an error for `SSLCertificateFile: file /path/to/my/certificate/fullchain.pem does not exist or is empty`. This is a normal situation or my SSL config is not correct?

Answer (score 5):

Fortunately, Most flavors of Linux have OpenSSL "out of the box".

## To verify installation:

`openssl version`
Response:
`OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016`

*Note: version OpenSSL 1.0.1 through 1.0.1f (inclusive)

are vulnerable to the OpenSSL Heartbleed Bug.

Versions 1.0.1g and greater are fixed.*

## For additional install info:

Ubuntu/Debian
`dpkg -l | grep -i openssl`
Response:
`ii  libcrypt-openssl-random-perl  0.04-2+b1       amd64  module to access the OpenSSL pseudo-random number generator

ii  libcurl3:amd64                 7.38.0-4+deb8u5 amd64  easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (OpenSSL flavour)

ii  libgnutls-openssl27:amd64      3.3.8-6+deb8u4  amd64  GNU TLS library - OpenSSL wrapper

ii  openssl                        1.0.1t-1+deb8u6 amd64  Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cryptographic utility

ii  python-ndg-httpsclient         0.3.2-1         all    enhanced HTTPS support for httplib and urllib2 using PyOpenSSL

ii  python-openssl                 0.14-1          all    Python 2 wrapper around the OpenSSL library

ii  ssl-cert                       1.0.35          all    simple debconf wrapper for OpenSSL`

Yea, OpenSSL is installed!

## To install OpenSSL if you don't have it, try:

Debian/Ubuntu:
`sudo apt-get install openssl`

RedHat/CentOS:
`yum install openssl`

Answer (score 4):

To determine **openssl** & **ssl_module**

```
# rpm -qa | grep openssl
openssl-libs-1.0.1e-42.el7.9.x86_64
openssl-1.0.1e-42.el7.9.x86_64
openssl098e-0.9.8e-29.el7.centos.2.x86_64
openssl-devel-1.0.1e-42.el7.9.x86_64
```

mod_ssl

```
# httpd -M | grep ssl
```

or

```
# rpm -qa | grep ssl
```

Answer (score 3):

You should install this Apache mod, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_info.html, it basically gives you a run down of the mods you're using and the Apache settings.
I have this enabled on my Apache and it gives me this info for my website,

Server Version: Apache/2.2.3 (Debian) mod_jk/1.2.18 PHP/5.2.0-8+etch13 mod_ssl/2.2.3 OpenSSL/0.9.8c mod_perl/2.0.2 Perl/v5.8.8

Answer (score 3):

If you just run `openssl` in your terminal it should present the openSSL shell.  My first clue to knowing that I didn't have `mode_ssl` was when I got the following error after adding `SSLEngine on` in my virtualhost file:

```
Invalid command 'SSLEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

In centos I just had to install it via `yum install mod_ssl`

Answer (score 3):

Just look in the *ssl_engine.log* in your Apache log directory where you should find something like:

```
[ssl:info] [pid 5963:tid 139718276048640] AH01876: mod_ssl/2.4.9 compiled against Server: Apache/2.4.9, Library: OpenSSL/1.0.1h
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a test.php file with the following code in a www folder:

```
<?php echo phpinfo();?>
```

When you navigate to that page/URL in the browser. You will see something similar if you have openssl enabled:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_ssl in httpd.conf and restart the apache. You will see the openssl information in error.log as below

```js
[Fri Mar 23 15:13:38.448268 2018] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 8891:tid 1] AH00292: Apache/2.4.29 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2n configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 23 15:13:38.448502 2018] [core:notice] [pid 8891:tid 1] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/apps/apache64/2.4.29/bin/httpd'
```

Answer (score 1):

to verify in php command lie

```
 $php -i | grep openssl
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case this is how I got the information:

- find where apache logs are located, and go there, in my case:

  `cd /var/log/apache2`
- find in which log openssl information can be found:

  `grep -i apache.*openssl *_log`

  `e.g. error_log ...`
- to get fresh information, restart apache, e.g.

  `rcapache2 restart # or service apache2 restart`
- check for last entries in the log, e.g.

  `/var/log/apache2 # tail error_log`

  `[Thu Jun 09 07:42:24 2016] [notice] Apache/... (Linux/...) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1t ...`

Answer (score -2):

To find the `ssl version`

1. Go to Apache bin folder in command prompt
2. Enter these commands "openssl version"